# What is meant by the 'linearity of quantum mechanics' in this derivation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, superposition

I saw an awesome derivation of [Schrodinger's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) on Wikipedia. Part of it relies on:

> If the wave-function at time $t$ is given by $\Psi(t)$, then by the linearity of quantum mechanics the wave-function at time $t'$ must be given by $\Psi(t') = U(t', t)\Psi(t)$, where $U(t', t)$ is a linear operator.

What is meant by *linearity of quantum mechanics* here?

Comment: @PhyEnthusiast I edited the titles of all four of your questions for posterity -- in the future, it's going to be hard for anybody interested in the stuff you asked to find it if it's called "understanding this derivation IV".

Comment: @PhyEnthusiast Also, consider making each question self-contained, i.e. quote the relevant part of the derivation in each one rather than linking back to this question.

Comment: More on [linearity of QM](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-mechanics+linear-systems+superposition).

Comment: This is one of the worst "it is possible to show that"s that I've seen in a long time.

Comment: @Mark Mitchison Meaning it is not true?

Comment: Meaning that it is a major omission that skips over almost everything non-trivial in the argument. Would you be satisfied with this  "derivation"?: It can be shown that the Schroedinger equation is correct. QED!! :) In any case, my comment is obsolete now after the recent edits.

Comment: @Mark Mitchison Yeah I wan't satisfied. But still it felt better than other derivations that I felt were clearly wrong.

Comment: Yes, the reason for that is that the Schroedinger equation *cannot be derived*. Its only justification is that it agrees with an enormously broad range of experiments. The best you can do is provide a plausibility argument, and that then depends on what you, subjectively, consider "plausible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am supposing you are not asking for a justification for why is quantum mechanics linear, because - as some comments already pointed out - the answer would be: it is because it is, unless some future experiment shows it is not.

This said, I am assuming you are asking why linearity in quantum mechanics implies that $\Psi(t')=U(t,t')\Psi(t)$. To keep things simple, suppose that the state at $t$ is the superposition of two states: $\Psi(t)=\psi_1(t)+\psi_2(t)$. A linear quantum evolution from time $t$ to time $t'$ means that exist a function $U_{t,t'}$ such that
$$
\Psi(t') = U_{t,t'}(\psi_1(t)+\psi_2(t))=U_{t,t'}(\psi_1(t))+U_{t,t'}(\psi_2(t)).
$$
That linear function is also supposed to satisfy $U_{t,t'}(0)=0$ and $U_{t,t'}(c\psi)=cU_{t,t'}(\psi)$, where $0$ is the zero vector and $\psi$ is an arbitrary state. The zero vector is not permissible as a quantum state, as the probability must sum up to one, and a constant multiplying an entire state can be incorporated into a normalizing factor. A function satisfying these properties is known as a linear operator as you almost certainly know. The probability must be conserved, so the norm of a quantum state must be conserved, what implies that this linear operator must be unitary. Rewriting 
$U_{t,t'}(\psi)$ as $U(t,t')\psi$ we finally arrive at
$$
\Psi(t')=U(t,t')\Psi(t).
$$

Comment: I was asking what linearity means? What does it mean to say that a certain mechanics is linear or non-linear

Comment: Mathematically it means the physical states form a vector space and time evolution is given by linear operators. Physically, it means that physical states can be superposed.

Comment: Think about electrostatics: suppose you want to compute the electric field produced by a charged sphere. As electrostatics is linear, you can divide the sphere in very tiny electric charge elements, use Coulomb's law to compute the electric field for each charge element and sum up all contributions obtaining the electric field at a certain position. You can sum up all contributions because electrostatics is linear. Linearity make things much more simple.